# Log every websocket messages

Tags: signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working on a blazorserver web application.

I would like to log in server console all websocket's blazor circuit messages. I want to log them as json, not msgpack.

Is there a way to do that with a hook or a middleware ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Bob, have you tried to configure your Blazor Signalr startup circuit with a log level with higher details? Look here for docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server#configure-signalr-client-logging-1

Comment: Yes i have tried this but i have not enough details... do you think i can create a custom circuit ? And how... thanks

Answer (score 0):

to achive this, you could do the following

```
services.AddServerSideBlazor()
        .AddHubOptions(options => {
           options.AddFilter<HubFilter>();
})
```

And then make a Hubfilter class, in my sample i am just counting the calls over the hub, but you could also log the message i suppose

```
public async ValueTask<object> InvokeMethodAsync(
        HubInvocationContext invocationContext, Func<HubInvocationContext, ValueTask<object>> next)
    {
        _memoryCache.Set("counter", _memoryCache.Get<int>("counter") + 1);
        Console.WriteLine($"☢️☢️☢️☢️ {_memoryCache.Get<int>("counter")}");
        try
        {
            return await next(invocationContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception calling '{invocationContext.HubMethodName}': {ex}");
            throw;
        }
    }

    // Optional method
    public Task OnConnectedAsync(HubLifetimeContext context, Func<HubLifetimeContext, Task> next)
    {
        return next(context);
    }

    // Optional method
    public Task OnDisconnectedAsync(
        HubLifetimeContext context, Exception exception, Func<HubLifetimeContext, Exception, Task> next)
    {
        return next(context, exception);
    }
}
```